# Chrome and Firefox not firing scroll event when reaching the top of the page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, scroll, event-handling

I need to be able to detect when the user scrolls to the top of the page, i.e. when `scrollTop <= 0`. In Chrome and Firefox, if a user scrolls fast enough, the scroll event is not guaranteed to always fire when the user reaches the top of the page. For example, if a user is 1500px down the page, and quickly scrolls up, the `scrollTop` value captured inside the last scroll event could be `1200`.

Safari's fix for this is to fire scroll events for over-scrolling, so scrollTop can be a negative value.

One option would be to listen to both `scroll` and `mousewheel` events, but that may not be super performant and still doesn't solve the issue of the user scrolling very fast by grabbing the scroll bar on the side of the page.

What is the best way to detect when the user reaches the top of the page?

Answer (score 1):

I think that if the scroll event is not guaranteed to always fire when the user reaches the top of the page, you can use the "setinterval" to verify the scrollTop at every second.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

see you